# Are production boosters limited to production dice rolls?

Tags: rivals-for-catan

The game include cards that double the production of resources in the neighbouring regions (Iron Foundry, Grain Mill, Brick Factory, Lumber Camp, Weaver's Shop).

Does the bonus apply every time we get a resource, or is it only limited to the production die rolls?

For instance, if I have a Lumber Camp next to a forest, and I trade 3 ores for lumber, do I get 1 or 2?

If I steal 1 lumber from my opponent (through Trade event, for example), do I get 1 or 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did some Googling and I found [an exhaustive FAQ on the Catan website](http://www.catan.com/faqs/104?page=8). Here's the answer to this question:

> Production boosters - Do production boosters have an effect when events occur and actions are performed, e.g., when I may choose any 1 resource or take 1 resource from my opponent?
>
> No.